# How do I prevent the application label and icon from appearing in the action bar on startup?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm using a logo in my application's action bar in my main activity.

When I launch my app, the app's icon and title label appear in place of the logo for a split second.

If I remove the label and icon attribute from the manifest, I lose the launcher icon from the app drawer and home screen, and the app's name is replaced with the package name.

If I add the logo attribute alongside the icon and label attribute, the app title flashes alongside the logo for a split second instead.

How do I get my app to startup with just the logo in the action bar but leave everything else like it should be?

Here is the relevant manifest snippet:

```
<application
    android:name=".activities.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.hello" >

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_leanpocket_logo" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25972954/437039) can help you. It helped me.

`<quote>`
Best method is to set the display options to `useLogo` in your theme. E.g.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">useLogo</item>
</style>
```

This won't actually show the logo (if set) because `showHome` is not included.
`</quote>`

Answer (score -1):

use Theme of No Title

#### Example

```
 <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" > // Like this
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Edit 1:
For Activity Title only (not for Application Title)

```
this.setTitle("");
```

By setting title to empty string you can achieve what you want

Comment: No this is different see it states about the theme about which i am talking about @prijupaul

Comment: Yes it will remove action bar

Comment: I see.  The question is not how to remove the action bar.  I wish to show my logo (which requires the action bar to be shown inside).

Comment: I am Updating but I don't know if it exactly concern with your problem

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work still.  The main activity doesn't have a title to begin with.  The title and icon that flashes I believe is coming from the <application> attributes.

Comment: @some_developer and You can not set application attributes dynamically

Comment: I don't know.  I can't imagine you are allowed to modify the manifest in code.

Comment: @some_developer you are not modifying manifest but you are dynamically setting TITLE or ICON of ACTIVITY at runtime

Comment: The ACTIVITY does not have a title or icon.  It only has a logo defined.  The title and icon that is being flashed is coming from the definition in the <application> node in the manifest.