# Navigation drawer forces app name and icon to appear shortly on startup

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Each time I start the app, the application name and icon appears very shortly on the left side over the drawer icon. This ruins the look of the custom `ActionBar` style.

How can I remove it? I already tried the top solution from StackOverflow, but they all refer to completely hiding the `ActionBar`. I don't want to hide it as I need it. I just don't know where to turn off this irritating display.

Note: I've let the Android Studio create the Navigation Drawer project for me so all the code came from the default creation.

**EDIT**

This is the code which appears in 3 locations: `restoreActionBar`, `setUp` and `showGlobalContextActionBar`. I am talking about the default Android Studio drawer project.

```
public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

//        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best method is to set the display options to `useLogo` in your theme. E.g.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">useLogo</item>
</style>
```

This won't actually show the logo (if set) because `showHome` is not included.

Comment: WOW! As simple as this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to use these

actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

Comment: Tried it before. It still displays the title+icon on startup shortly.And I've searched for all usages of `actionBar` in the code and added these lines accordingly.

Comment: Is there anything you have declared  in your styles?